# How to solve Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to a swift, please someone help/advise me. 
And I am sending the request to a server and using completionBlock. When login button clicks the success completionBlock is calling and here i am getting struck.

This is my request

```
typealias CompletionBlock = ( _ response : Any , _ error : Error) -> Void


    func login(userName: String, password: String, completionBlock: @escaping CompletionBlock ) -> Void
{
    let parameter = ["gs_username":userName, "gs_password":password] as [String : AnyObject]
     let url = "user-login"
    let fullUrl = baseUrl?.appendingPathComponent(url)
    if ((userName != nil) && (password != nil)) {

        Alamofire.request(fullUrl!, method: .post, parameters: parameter, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    let json = response.result.value
                    completionBlock(json as Any, response.error!)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("getEvents error: \(error)")
                    //completionBlock(nil as AnyObject, error)
                    break
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error line

```
 completionBlock(json as Any, response.error!)
```

Comment: on which line you are getting error? have to check by applying exception break point?

Comment: What is the value in json? if it is nill, change this line by completionBlock(json as? Any, response.error!) and then check

Comment: `response.error` is nil, and therefore `response.error!` crashes ...

Comment: @aBilal17, Crash is not occurred at `json as Any`, crash occurred at `response.error!`.

Comment: Your `response.error` in `.success` case is `nil` (no error, connection is successful), and you're trying to explicitly unwrap that value. Change the error code to an empty string or some other appropriate type, and it should be ok.

Comment: @aBilal17 This line completionBlock(json as Any, response.error!)

Comment: ok,, just update this line by this new line and then check. completionBlock(json as Any, "No Error found")

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update as below

```
func login(userName: String?, password: String?, completionBlock: @escaping CompletionBlock ) -> Void
{
    let parameter = ["gs_username":userName, "gs_password":password] as [String : AnyObject]
     let url = "user-login"
    let fullUrl = baseUrl?.appendingPathComponent(url)
    if ((userName != nil) && (password != nil)) {

        Alamofire.request(fullUrl!, method: .post, parameters: parameter, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    let json = response.result.value
                    completionBlock(json as Any, "No Error found")
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("getEvents error: \(error)")
                    //completionBlock(nil as AnyObject, error)
                    break
                   }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to OP and to future readers) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of dumping code only.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Patel thanks for answering, But its not taking a string value and i changed this line completionBlock(json as Any, "No Error found" as! Error) . But i got error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error and in console "Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x10781a9f8) to 'Swift.Error' (0x7f88708e5798). "

Comment: @Appu, you need to change your `completionBlock` param. `Error` to `String` than this code will work.

Comment: make as --> typealias CompletionBlock = ( _ response : Any , _ error : String) -> Void

Comment: Thanks @Kuldeep its working fine

Comment: thanks @RakeshPatel

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Patel I have one more question here i am checking      if ((userName != nil) && (password != nil)){   }.  i am getting this warning "Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil always returns true" how to fix this line.

Comment: might be your username or password has nonoptional value...can you update your code in question where you set username and password?

Comment: Please check my updated answer...-->login(userName: String?, password: String?

Comment: Yes it's working, Thank you so much @RakeshPatel

Comment: Hi @RakeshPatel i have one more doubt please solve this one, I set completionBlock in failer case. But its showing error "Expression type 'Void' is ambiguous without more context".

Comment: How you set completion block? can  you show me?

Comment: @RakeshPatel typealias CompletionBlock = ( _ response : Any , _ error : String) -> Void     This is my completionBlock

Comment: i mean what you pass  as parameter in completionblock in failure case

Comment: i think you should pass --> completionBlock("No Data found", error)

Comment: completionBlock(nil as Any, "Some errors are found")

Comment: Now its working fine, Thanks Rakesh. completionBlock("No Data found", "Some errors are found")

Comment: thats great...!!.  I advise you to do clear a concept of optional and nonoptional value in swift.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much